# Wrong positioning of subscripts on bold math letters

Tags: fonts, math-mode, bold, subscripts, kerning

I just noticed that for `kpfonts` and `times` (and probably other fonts since it does not seem to be font-related), the subscripts on boldface letters like V are (I would say) wrong. Is there an explanation?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{A}_a$ $A_a$ $\mathbf{V}_a$ $V_a$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just using `\bf{A}_a`? I was instructed by more senior posters here to never use `\mathbf{ }` in `mathmode`.

Comment: @Jase I believe that senior posters here recommend to *never* use `\bf`.

Comment: @egreg Oh yes, you're right. I had a false memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implicit kerning is not taken into account for math letters and their subscripts. Only the italic correction is considered. As workaround the spacing can be manually fixed, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{A}_a^a$ $A_a^a$ $\mathbf{V}_a^a$ $V_a^a$
$\mathbf{V}_{\!\!a}$ $V_{\!a}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Package `times` does not matter, because it was only used for the page number.

Comment: Thanks. And this implicit kerning could be taken into account in the future, or it is just not possible.